# Error iterating over a list 'TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable object'

Tags: python, scipy

I'm writing a Python script to solve a certain differential equation with SciPy's odeint. I just copied the example on the doc page:

```
def pend(y,t,b,c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega -c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt
b = 0.25
c = 5.0

y0 = [np.pi-0.1,0.0]
t = np.linspace(0,10,101)
sol = odeint(pend, y0, t, args = (b,c))
plt.plot(t,sol[:,1])
plt.plot(t,sol[:,0])
```

This works fine and everything but when I try with the Lotka-Volterra system the code breaks down:

```
def F(t,n,a,b,c,d):
    x, y = n
    deriv = [a*x-b*x*y,c*x*y-d*y]
    return deriv

t = np.linspace(0,100,100)
a = 1.1
b= 0.4
c = 0.1
d = 0.4
n0 = [10,10]
sol = odeint(F,n0,t,args = (a,b,c,d))
```

This returns a TypeError

```
<ipython-input-14-ea2a41feaef2> in F(t, n, a, b, c, d)
     1 def F(t,n,a,b,c,d):
----> 2     x, y = n
     3     deriv = [a*x-b*x*y,c*x*y-d*y]
     4     return deriv
     5 

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object
```

Could anyone help me see what I'm missing? Specifically, why does the example code work if the second code is written with the same structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that the arguments passed in this line are not in the right order:

```
sol = odeint(F,n0,t,args = (a,b,c,d))
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
sol = odeint(F,t,n0,args = (a,b,c,d))
```

---

Alternatively you can swap the argument order in the function definition to:

```
def F(n,t,a,b,c,d):
```